# Unexpected result using Spacy regex

Tags: python, regex, spacy-3

I find an unexpected result matching regular expresions using Spacy (version 3.1.3).
I define a simple regex to identify a digit. Then I create strings made of a digit and a letter and try to identify then. Everything work as expected but with letters g, m and t:

Here is a minimal implementation

```
import string 
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()
pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "\d"}}]
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("usage",[pattern])

for l in string.ascii_lowercase:
    doc = nlp(f"2{l}")
    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
        span = doc[start:end]
        print(l, span.text)
```

result

```
a 2a
b 2b
c 2c
d 2d
e 2e
f 2f
g 2    # EXPECTED 2g
h 2h
i 2i
j 2j
k 2k
l 2l
m 2   # EXPECTED 2m
n 2n
o 2o
p 2p
q 2q
r 2r
s 2s
t 2   # EXPECTED 2t
u 2u
v 2v
w 2w
x 2x
y 2y
z 2z
```

Comment: These strings are tokenized as two tokens, `['2', 'g']`, `['2', 'm']`, `['2', 't']`. So the result is actually as expected. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In my case I have a strings like "some 1.2t other stuff 1.2a", I would expect to detect 1.2t and 1.2a but what I get is 1.2 and 1.2a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings in question are split into two tokens:

```py
2g => ['2', 'g']
2m => ['2', 'm']
2t => ['2', 't']
```

In order to match the pattern, you need to account for the fact the `g`, `m` or `t` letter can be the next token.

In that case, you can use

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()
pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "\d"}}, {"TEXT": {"REGEX": "^[gmt]$"}, "OP": "?"}]
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("usage",[pattern])

text = "some 1.2t other stuff 1.2a"
doc = nlp(text)
matches = matcher(doc)
spans = [doc[start:end] for _, start, end in matches]
for span in spacy.util.filter_spans(spans):
    print(span.text)
```

Here, the `pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "\d"}}, {"TEXT": {"REGEX": "^[gmt]$"}, "OP": "?"}]` pattern matches the token with a digit first, and then - optionally (due to `"OP": "?"`) - a token that is equal to `m`, `g` or `t`. `spacy.util.filter_spans` only keeps the longest matches.

You might make the pattern a bit more precise if you only match a number as the first token. In this case, change `"REGEX": "\d"` to `"REGEX": "^\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]?$"` (matches `5`/`5a` or `55.555`/`55.555a` like numbers) or `"REGEX": "^\d*\.?\d+[a-z]?$"` (this one also matches `.5`/`.5a` like strings), and then the second. Or, better use two patterns:

```py
pattern = [
    [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "^\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]$"}}],
    [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$"}}, {"TEXT": {"REGEX": "^[gmt]$"}}]
]
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("usage", pattern)
```